# tickets modx how to get to preview content

Tags: modx

Recently I installed MODX Tickets as reviews/comments system. It has "preview" option for quick overview of  the comment. So here comes the problem: if unauthorized person try to preview his comment he'll see the name he typed in comment form field before

```
<input type="text" class="text form-control" name="name" id="comment-name" value="[[+name]]" placeholder="Your name"/>
```

and all is fine,but if authorized person try to do so - he'll see the name from his profile (fullname). And I want to change this behavior so only name from form field should appear,but not from profile field.
Please give any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Done. i just found it here **assets/components/tickets/js/web/default.js**

```
comment: {
        preview: function(form,button) {
            var trueName = $(form).find("#comment-name").val(); //I place it here

            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                data: {action: 'comment/preview'}
                ,url: TicketsConfig.actionUrl
                ,form: form
                ,button: button
                ,dataType: 'json'
                ,beforeSubmit: function(formData, form, options) {
                    // FishSpace: support attachments
                    Tickets.comment.addAttachmentsToText(form, formData);
                    // endof FishSpace
                    $(button).attr('disabled','disabled');
                    return true;
                }
                ,success: function(response) {
                    $(button).removeAttr('disabled');
                    if (response.success) {
                        $('#comment-preview-placeholder').html(response.data.preview).show();
                        $('#comment-preview-placeholder').find('.ticket-comment-author').text(trueName);//and here
                        prettyPrint();
                    }
                    else {
                        Tickets.Message.error(response.message);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```

So it fixed my problem.I know it is not good to edit source files but I run out of time.